# Canceling JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, promise, cancellation, google-closure-library

I am using Google JS closure library 
https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

I have the following code:

```
if (endDate >= wap.com.ifx.util.IfxComponentUtil.yyyymmdd(currentDate) && goog.object.isEmpty(token)) {
    if (goog.isDefAndNotNull(this.reloadGridPromise_)) {
      this.reloadGridPromise_.cancel('[INFO]Canceling');
    }
    this.reloadGridPromise_ = new wap.core.net.partialupdate.partialUpdate('getFilteredHistoryList?' + get_params(
      vars), this.updateGridFlag);
    var self = this;
    this.reloadGridPromise_.then(function(response) {
//something
}
```

This block of code repeates every 5 seconds. I can see the following requests in Google CHrome developer tools

[image]

When I debug the `js` code, I see that this statement `this.reloadGridPromise_.cancel('[INFO]Canceling');` is being executed. However, I can't see any change in the requests in Chrome developer tools.

Google clousre promise
https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.Promise.html

Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: Try `return this.reloadGridPromise_.cancel('[INFO]Canceling');`

Answer (score 0):

You can not cancel Promises. If you wan't to cancel a request, you have to use Obesrvers instead of promises. So maybe have a look at: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/